# TikZ: Access coordinates of decorated paths?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to access the coordinates of the decoration of some paths? I draw two paths, e.g., with:

```
   \begin{figure}[t]
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw [red,decorate,decoration={crosses, segment length=1.05cm,
           transform={shift only}}]
             {(4, 4) .. controls(6, 3.5) .. (8, 4)};
       \draw [red,decorate,decoration={crosses, segment length=1.05cm,
           transform={shift only}}]
             {(4, 4) .. controls(6, 4.5) .. (8, 4)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{figure}
```

Each of these paths contains some crosses I would like to connect with some arrows. If I could access the coordinates of the crosses, this would be quite simple. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but you could modify the decoration to add coordinates at each of the points.  Would that be acceptable?

Comment: At least, this would be a very good workaround. How to do this?

Comment: You define a new decoration (probably a marking) that does the same as the cross that you have but adds a coordinate as well.  The label for the coordinate should be of the form `<base>-<number>` where `<base>` is user-specified and `<number>` is incremented for each cross.  There are lots of examples of modifying decorations on this site, I'm trying to find the most appropriate (my search skills are not great!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to do it which works by modifying the `crosses` decoration to add a labelling to each cross.  You have the option to specify the prefix of the labelling and the numerical index increments as the decoration places crosses.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65557/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\makeatletter
% crosses decoration

\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/label cross name/.initial=cross}
\newcount\pgf@lblcross@index

\pgfdeclaredecoration{labelled crosses}{init}
{
  \state{init}[width=+0pt,next state=crosses,persistent
precomputation={
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/decoration/label cross name}{\pgf@lblcross}
  \global\pgf@lblcross@index=0\relax
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/shape start
width}/2}
    \edef\pgf@lib@dec@ssw{\pgfmathresult pt}
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/shape start
height}/2}
    \edef\pgf@lib@dec@ssh{\pgfmathresult pt}
  }]{}  
  \state{crosses}[switch if less than=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to
last,
                  width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfcoordinate{\pgf@lblcross-\the\pgf@lblcross@index}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \global\advance\pgf@lblcross@index by 1\relax
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{\pgf@lib@dec@ssh}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssh}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssh}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{\pgf@lib@dec@ssh}}
  }
  \state{last}[width=+\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance]
  {
    \pgfcoordinate{\pgf@lblcross-\the\pgf@lblcross@index}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \global\advance\pgf@lblcross@index by 1\relax
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{\pgf@lib@dec@ssh}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssh}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssh}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{\pgf@lib@dec@ssh}}
  }
  \state{final}{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw [postaction={draw=red,decorate},decoration={labelled
crosses, label cross name=A, segment length=1.05cm,
           transform={shift only}}]
             {(4, 4) .. controls(6, 3.5) .. (8, 4)};
       \draw [postaction={draw=red,decorate},decoration={labelled
crosses, label cross name=B, segment length=1.05cm,
           transform={shift only}}]
             {(4, 4) .. controls(6, 4.5) .. (8, 4)};
             \draw[->,green,dashed] (A-1) to[bend right] (B-2);
             \draw[->,green,dashed] (A-3) to[bend left] (B-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Labelled crosses on a path]

(Actually, it doesn't but only because after generating the real picture I decided that it was too small to see what was going on so I scaled it up, but I couldn't be bothered to change the code above.)